# How to fill a form using the form name in CasperJS

Tags: html, forms, casperjs

I'm trying to fill the inputs of a form:

```
<form name="step_one_login_form" action="/" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="step_one_login_form">
  <input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="index.php?
  <div id="haveaccount" style="display:block;">
    <div class="panel_login">
      <div class="panel_login_row">
        <div class="panel_login_fieldname">
          <label for="login_checkout" class="cm-required cm-trim cm-email">Email:</label>
          <span class="panel_login_fieldabout">(Required)</span>
        </div>
      <div class="panel_login_field">
        **<input type="text" id="login_checkout" name="user_login" size="30" value=""class="panel_login_textbox">**
```

Since the class or id of the form is not given, I don't understand the way to do it.

Comment: All of the CSS3 selectors supports at casper.fill("<css3 selector>").

Answer (score 7):

Since it has the `name` attribute, you can reference it with that.

```
casper.fill('form[name="step_one_login_form"]', {
    'user_login': 'USER_NAME'
});
```

You could also use the `Casper#fillSelectors` method:

```
casper.fillSelectors('form[name="step_one_login_form"]', {
    '#login_checkout': 'USER_NAME'
});
```

Comment: Note that fillSelectors is available in casperjs >= 1.1.